# memcpy issues; copying wrong block and multiple times

Tags: c++, combinators

```````
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int sk00(char * a)                    //use to find length, in characters, of an expression
{
    int b = 1, c = 0;
    while(b != 0)
    {
        if (a[c] == '`'){b++;}
        else{b--;}
        c++;
    }
    return c;
}

void sk07(char * a)
{
    int b = 0; while(a[b]!=0){b++;}b -= 2;
    memcpy(a,a+3,b);
    memcpy(a+sk00(a),a+sk00(a)+sk00(a+sk00(a)),b);
}

void sk20(char * z)
{
    char * a = z + 2;
    int b = 0;while(a[b]!=0){b++;}b-=1;
    memcpy(a,a+2,b);
    int al = sk00(a), bl = sk00(a+al), cl = sk00(a+al+bl);
    b=b-(al+bl+cl);
    memcpy(a+al+cl+1, a+al, b+cl+bl);
}

int main()
{
    char a[] = "``````s`k`sikabcd";
    sk20(a+3);
    cout << a << "; Final.\n";
}
```````

Terminal Output:

```````
pup@aurora-217:~/sk$ g++ sk5.c
pup@aurora-217:~/sk$ ./a.out
``````k`sikakakad; Final.
pup@aurora-217:~/sk$
```````

I'm expecting an output along the lines of

``````
`````ksik`sikabcd
``````

Comment: i tried to look at the code, but i felt a bit dizzy after one second of deeply staring at it

Comment: Have you tried to run your code in the debugger? Which line works not as you expected?

Comment: The choice of identifiers is probably not the best, you should aim to provide better identifiers than  `sk00`, `sk07` or `sk20`. Determine what each function is meant to do and use a name that helps understanding it. Also a brief description of what you are trying to do would help others understand the code and provide helpful comments.

Comment: @Rob, things like this, you need debug yourself and boil down to the specific code that you have question on, instead of letting us figure out and debug this whole stuff for you.

Comment: It's always the last line of sk20 that doesn't work. 
And to be fair, I've been trying to figure this out for hours. I had assumed memcpy could work with overlapping blocks.

Comment: @Robert: from the manpage: "The memory areas should not overlap.  Use memmove(3) if the memory areas do overlap."

Answer (score 1):

Technically you have a problem in sk07 if and when b is larger than 2 or 3, as you cannot use memcpy for cases where the source and target overlaps. You could try memmove instead.

Whether we have an overlap here, for example

```
memcpy(a+al+cl+1, a+al, b+cl+bl);
```

is very hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of potentially overlapping memory locations, which it looks like is the case in your code you should use the memmove function rather than the memcpy routine. The memcpy routine is considered unsafe to use in the case of overlapping memory locations and because of optimizations can make a complete mess of the resulting output.

memmove takes the same parameters in the same order as memcpy and so can just be used as a drop in replacement.